# How to get NSTimer to loop

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer, foundation

I'm trying to learn about `NSTimer`, using Foundation and printing to the console. Can anybody tell me what I need to do to get the following to work? It compiles with no errors, but does not activate my `startTimer` method -- nothing  prints.

My aim is to get one method to call another method to run some statements, and then stop after a set time.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyTime : NSObject {
    NSTimer *timer;
}
- (void)startTimer;
@end

@implementation MyTime

- (void)dealloc {
    [timer invalidate];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)startTimer {
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(runTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)runTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    NSLog(@"timer fired");
}
@end


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];


    MyTime *timerTest = [[MyTime alloc] init];
    [timerTest startTimer];

    [timerTest release];

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please reward the people who have helped you in the past and accept answers to your older question.

Answer (score 6):

The timer never gets a chance to fire in your program, because the program ends almost immediately after the timer is created.

There's a construct called the [Run Loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) which is responsible for processing input, including input from timers. One run loop is created for each thread, but it isn't automatically started in this case.

You need to run the run loop and keep it going until the timer has a chance to fire. Fortunately, this is quite easy. Insert:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.0]];
```

between sending `startTimer` and `release` to `timerTest`. If you want the timer to repeat, you'll need to continue keeping the run loop active.

Note that you only need to do that in a simple program like this; when you are creating an application with a GUI, the run loop will be started via the Cocoa application setup process, and will remain active until the application terminates.

Comment: I don't think it's quite accurate to say "when the main function ends, the run loop ends too." I mean, it is true that the program exiting will terminate the runloop, but that isn't the issue here. In this particular example, no runloop is ever even started.

Comment: @Chuck: I was actually trying to puzzle that point out just now. I was under the impression that the loop was started automatically by the [NS?]thread, but I guess it's actually done by AppKit?

Comment: Every NSThread *has* a runloop, but it doesn't run until it's told to. In a normal Cocoa application, the main loop is run by `NSApplicationMain()`. I think that's what it is referring to in the docs when it says that function "runs the application."

Comment: @pete: Glad it helped. Please don't forget to click the checkmark on this and answers to your other questions when they solve your problem. This lets others know the question is resolved, and rewards the answerer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/ for details, as I linked above.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add your timer to the default runloop after initializing it:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Put this in `-(void)startTimer.`

Comment: I have just copy and pasted that into the -(void)startTimer but its still not working. If placed above timer statement it does nothing as before. If placed below, I get a Thread! bad error. What suggest looks good - could you try again ? thanks Tim.

Comment: Placing it below is the right place to put it.  The problem is that in your program you're starting the timer and then immediately releasing the object containing it and it's still in the runloop, so when it gets called the object it operates on (in this case `testTimer`) is already gone and that's why you get an error.

Comment: This is only correct if you don't use the scheduledTimer family of classes, which he is using.

Comment: Ive moved it below as suggested and removed [timerTest release]; but its still not working -

Comment: so any ideas on how I can achieve my original aim as above ?

Comment: The problem is not, in this case, that the timer's target (`testTimer`) is deallocated, but that the run loop ends before the timer can fire. You are correct to point that out as a something to watch out for, however. It _will_ cause a crash if the timer fires after its target has been destroyed.

Comment: @Tim: The `scheduledTimer…` family of constructors automatically add the timer to the run loop. The problem here is that he is never running the runloop, so it will never fire the timers.

Comment: I suppose in a way that was my original question - how to start the loop ? is it just the runTimer method that should loop ?