# what's wrong with this simple code(objective c)?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

i want to download some webpages ,but this example code seems doesn't work.
it prints "begin download" and then exits,why the delegates method does not be executed? 
what's wrong in the example code?
thanks

```
main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Test.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Test * test = [[Test alloc]init];
        [test downloadData];

    }
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:21.0f];

    return 0;
}

Test.h


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Test : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate>
@property (retain) NSMutableData * receivedData;
@property (retain) NSURLConnection * theConnection;
- (void) downloadData;
@end

Test.m

#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test
- (void) downloadData
{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=
      [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sf.net/"]                                  
                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

    _receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];



    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                          returningResponse:nil
                                      error:nil];
    NSLog(@"begin download");

    if (!_theConnection) {

        _receivedData = nil;

        // Inform the user that the connection failed.

    }
}

enter code here

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataDelegateenter code here methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{
    NSLog(@"1");
    [_receivedData setLength:0];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{
    NSLog(@"2");
    [_receivedData appendData:data];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection

  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

{
    NSLog(@"3");
    _theConnection = nil;

    _receivedData = nil;



    // inform the user

    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",

          [error localizedDescription],

          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{


    NSLog(@"4");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %lu bytes of data",(unsigned long)[_receivedData length]);



    _theConnection = nil;

    _receivedData = nil;

}

-(void) connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
{
    NSLog(@"5");
}
@end
```

Comment: Same problem as [How to get NSTimer to loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055629/how-to-get-nstimer-to-loop)

Comment: In short: Your program needs a run loop.

Comment: You are using a synchronous request. Your delegate methods won't get called. Assign the result of your request to an nsdata object `NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest....];` or use asynchronous request and set the delegate!

Comment: thanks ,
i changed     

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:21.0f];     
to
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:50.0]];

and
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                          returningResponse:nil
                                      error:nil];
to
    _theConnection= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

run it again，
it prints 

 begin download
 1
 <>
 5

only two method is called and the data is still null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two ways to Synchronous or Asynchonous :

In Synchronous any delegates was not called and the right line is 
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest%3areturningResponse%3aerror%3a)

```
_receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                          returningResponse:nil
                                      error:nil];
    NSLog(@"begin download");

    if (!_theConnection) {

        _receivedData = nil;

        // Inform the user that the connection failed.

    }
```

In Asynchronous you need to use – initWithRequest:delegate:
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/initWithRequest:delegate:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/initWithRequest%3adelegate%3a%22iniWithRequest%22)

```
[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:delegate:theRequest
                          delegate:self];

NSLog(@"begin download");
```